# Merge dynamic-generated .txt file in .ino file using #include

Tags: c, arduino, include, arduino-ide

I'm doing a 'scheduling' program in Arduino, has to send many string commands according to time of the day.

The way I use is - is to make a 'for' loop that runs over the needed times, and if the current time is relevant to run something - it runs a 'switch' command to run the correct code.

Here is the code sample of my 'for' function:

```
void CheckIfAction(const RtcDateTime& dt) {
    const int A = 6;    // Action Array Size
    int ActionTimes[A][4] = {
        {6,18,37,1},
        {6,18,38,2},
        {5,15,20,11},
        {5,16,45,51},
        {5,16,50,52},
        {5,23,35,15}   
    };
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < A; i++ ) {

        if ((dt.DayOfWeek()==ActionTimes[i][0]) && (dt.Hour()==ActionTimes[i][1]) && (dt.Minute()==ActionTimes[i][2]) && (dt.Second() < 2)) {
            RunMyAction(ActionTimes[i][3]);
        }
    } 
}
```

And here is the Switch:

```
void RunMyAction(const int& MyActionCode)
{
    switch(MyActionCode) {
    case 1:
        digitalWrite(2, LOW);  // Turn the LED on by making the voltage LOW
        // Serial.println("Time condition is met, LED is ON");
        Serial.println("S041OFE");
        delay(1500);
        Serial.println("S041ONE");
        delay(1500);
        Serial.println("S041OFE");
        delay(1500);
        Serial.println("S041ONE");
        break;  
    case 2:
        digitalWrite(2, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
        Serial.println("S017ONE");
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println("S017OFE");
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println("S017ONE");
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println("S017OFE");
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println("S017ONE");
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println("S017OFE");
        delay(1000);
        break;        
    case 11:     //Before Knissat Shabat - Full status update.
        Serial.println("S01D00000D00ES02D01001100ES03D00101101ES04D1100D0DDES05D10011DDDE");
        delay(1000);
        break;
    case 15:     //Last GoodNight Shabat - Full status update.
        Serial.println("S01D00000000ES02D00000000ES03D00000100ES04D1000D00DES05D00011DDDE");
        delay(1500);
        break;
    case 51:
        Serial.println("S036OFE");
        delay(1500);
        break;
    case 52:
        Serial.println("S047OFES036ONE");
        delay(1500);


        break;
    //#include "ExcelActions.txt"
    }
}
```

To make things easier, I'm trying to use Excel to generate the "case" parts according to a list of functions I have in it, and (as you can see in the last command above) to include the well-styled generated file instead of typing it or copy/pasting it.

My questions:
1. Can I really include a text file in that place like I typed it myself,
2. Where should I place that file for Arduino IDE to find it. I tried to put it in the directory of the .ino file, and got compile error - "File or directory doesn't exist".

Many thanks!

Comment: No you can't include a `.txt` file. Also it isn't really clear what you are trying to do. What is the content of the `.txt` file?  Why do you try to include it? What is your total `.ino` file (it looks like you can refactor alot)?

Comment: As you may see from the code, I have a set of strings that should be sent to a serial device at given times (according to day of the week, hour and minute). There are about 60 'events' like those. So the simple way is just to hard-code the 60 events as 'cases' of the switch command. But I wanted to do it more clever way - make an Excel table with strings, and let it generate the 'case' formats and include it in the Arduino code. Hope this makes my intension more clear. Thanks!

Comment: could you add your main loop function? Trying to figure out how it fits together. The one thing that jumps out now is your declaration of `ActionTimes` in `CheckIfAction`. This is unnecessary and slows down the program, should outside the scope. || As for the the `case`s, I wouldn't use Excel but generate a list with Python. Can you post a small example of your .txt?

Comment: You're right about the wrong place I put the array decleation. I just was worried about scope, so I didn't put it in the setup(). I should probably put it before setup() function, so it will become globat. About the format and the Excel - I hope to soon edit my question here and put more information. Many thanks!

Comment: As I said - ""BEFORE setup() function"... working on it. Thanks.